# Вывод нечётных элементов массива через запятую Java

Tags: java, массивы

помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться :  есть метод printOddNumbers, который принимает массив и выводит в консоль только нечетные числа из него, через запятую. Конец вывода должен перевести курсор на новую строку.

Пример ввода: `[3,5,20,8,7,3,100]`

Пример вывода: `3,5,7,3`

У меня на выходе получается : `3,5,7,3,`

То есть мне нужно убрать последнюю запятую.

Помогите, пожалуйста, как  можно убрать запятую в конце?

Также у меня не работает этот код в случае если элементы массива отрицательные. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти баг. Заранее спасибо.

Ссылка на онлайн-компилятор с кодом:

https://paiza.io/projects/OVNkb7xbg3IMP9liR15thg?language=java

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] strArray = new int[]{3, 5, 20, 8, 7, 3, 100};
    printOddNumbers(strArray);
}

public static void printOddNumbers(int[] arr) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 1)
            if ((i == arr.length - 1)) {
                stringBuilder.append(arr[i]);
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append(arr[i] + ",");
            }
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuilder);
    stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

Output: `3,5,7,3,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void printOddNumbers(int[] arr) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int value : arr) {
        if (value % 2 == 1) {
            stringBuilder.append(value + ",");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.substring(0,stringBuilder.length()-1));
}
```

или

```
public static void printOddNumbers(int[] arr) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int value : arr) if (value % 2 == 1) stringBuilder.append(value + ",");
    stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length()-1);
    System.out.println(stringBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Jackson750, спасибо!

Comment: @user4166 кликни на верный ответ. Постать галочку

Comment: Готово) поставила

Answer (score 1):

> Помогите, пожалуйста, как можно убрать запятую в конце?

А зачем вы ее добавляете?

```
stringBuilder.append(arr[i] + ",");
```

для каждого элемента в конце добавляется запятая. Тут есть три решения

1. После цикла удалять из StringBuilder последнюю запятую

   ```
   if (stringBuilder.length() > 0)
     stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1)
   ```
2. Добавлять запятую **перед** элементом для всех, кроме первого

   ```
   if (stringBuilder.length() > 0)
     stringBuilder.append(',');
   stringBuilder.append(arr[i]);
   ```
3. Добавлять нужные элементы в список, а потом вызвать `Arrays.toString(tmpList)`

> не работает этот код в случае если элементы массива отрицательные

Потому, что остаток от деления отрицательного нечетного числа на 2 будет `-1`. Поэтому если проверку на нечетность переписать вот так

```
if (arr[i] % 2 != 0)
```

то код будет работать как с положительными, так и с отрицательными числами

Кроме того, при таком цикле

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
> ```

вы будете пропускать последний элемент массива. Цикл должен быть таким

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть интересный класс StringJoiner для таких вещей.

Вот пример:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",", "", "\r\n");
    int[] arr = {3,5,20,8,7,3,100};
    for (int e : arr) {
        if (e % 2 != 0)
            joiner.add(String.valueOf(e));
    }
    System.out.println(joiner.toString());
}
```

Comment: Sergey, спасибо, очень полезный ответ)

Answer (score 0):

```
string.substring(0,string.length() -1)
```

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за помощь!!! Хорошего дня :)

Answer (score 0):

У вас условие выхода из цикла неверное

```
 i < arr.length - 1
```

единицу не нужно отнимать, из-за этого последний элемент массива вообще не анализируется. Нужно так:

```
i < arr.length
```

Эта строчка вообще лишняя, так как она по сути ничего не делает, а перевод строки вам делает `System.out.println`

```
stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Условие на запятую неверное, так как оно сработает, только если у вас последний элемент нечетный. Логичнее в данном случае запятую проставлять перед числом, а не после. Для отрицательных берите модуль от остатка. По итогу будет как-то так:

```
public static void printOddNumbers(int[] arr) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(arr[i] % 2) == 1)
            if (first) {
                stringBuilder.append(arr[i]);
                first = false;
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append("," + arr[i]);
            }
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Iksuy, большое спасибо за помощь :) хорошего Вам дня!

Answer (score 0):

ну и стримы то почему никто не предложил

```
int[] strArray = new int[]{3, 5, 20, 8, 7, 3, 100};
String result = IntStream.of(strArray)
        .filter(i -> (i & 1) != 0)
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод [`Stream.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) позволяет расширить текущий стрим дополнительными элементами:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printOddNumbers(new int[]{3, 5, 20, 8, 7, 3, 100}); // 3,5,7,3
}

public static void printOddNumbers(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.stream(arr)
            // нечетные числа
            .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
            // число в виде строки
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
            // добавляем запятую перед
            // каждой строкой
            .flatMap(i -> Stream.of(",", i))
            // пропускаем первую запятую
            .skip(1)
            // выводим в одну строку
            .forEach(System.out::print);
    // перевод курсора
    // на новую строку
    System.out.println();
}
```